# export data is not working for more then 4 Dimensions in icCube-7.9

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

we tried to export the data (in excel format) from a table with 5 Dimensions, but it did not work. However, when we reduced the number of the dimensions to 4, it did work.

is there any thing to do to increase the number of the dimension and be able to export the data?

Comment: Is that a regular or a pivot-table? Can you please mention the faulty query?

Comment: we are using a pivot-table and faulty query will be sent to you per mail .

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem has been fixed in the latest version of the icCube reporting application.

Answer (score 0):

yes, we can confirm that! it is working now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).